# How is (non-interfering) data communication possible over the tv spectrum? What is the technology used?

Tags: wireless, communication, fcc, tv, spectrum

I've heard that FCC-US (Federal Communication Commission - United States) has approved the free usage of TV spectrum for wireless communication. How is it possible to enable such data communication over TV bands without interfering the TV channels? What is the technology used? Is it available for unlicensed public use?

A news link is given below

http://gigaom.com/2012/09/06/need-spectrum-fcc-plans-tv-incentive-auction-for-2014/

Comment: What do you mean by "TV spectrum"? There are different bands used for TV broadcasting, and I can't believe the FCC with throw them all together and call them "TV spectrum".

Comment: By TV spectrum, it doesn't mean the entire frequency band available for broadcasting. There are some terms and conditions. I've read this from the news posting given below 
http://news.cnet.com/8301-13578_3-57522584-38/fcc-kicks-off-effort-to-reclaim-tv-spectrum-for-wireless/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, i found that the wireless data communication over TV spectrum is made possible through the [IEEE 802.22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.22) (Super-Wifi) technology which is a Wireless Regional Area Network (WRAN) standard. It uses the [white space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spaces_%28radio%29) available in the TV frequency spectrum. The interference with TV channels are prevented by means of [Cognitive Radio (CR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_radio) technique as well as other spectrum sensing and allocation methodologies. IEEE 802.22 uses VHF/UHF TV broadcast bands between 54 MHz to 862 MHz.

The standard is currently proposed for unlicensed public use. The theoretical range of this network is upto 100km with wired broadband compatible speed (1.5Mbps).